# I need help understanding how to fix this: expected expression swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num);

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, cs50, swap, function-definition

I am having trouble figuring out what I did wrong here. Im not sure what expression the compiler is needing.
This is the error:  expected expression swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num);

I have tried googling this error but most of the answers say that I didnt declare it. However, I thought i did declare it when i included the cs50 library. For clarity, I am in the cs50x class at harvard and I have heard in the past that this library is class specific, so I tried running this in our compiler in class and it still says this.

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num);

int main(void)

{

  int first_num = get_int("Input 1st number:\n");

  int second_num = get_int("Input 2nd number:\n");

  swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num);

  printf("First_num = %i\n", first_num);
  printf("Second_num = %i\n", second_num);
}

int swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num)

{

  int temp_num = second_num;

  first_num = temp_num;

  second_num = first_num;
}
```

Comment: This record swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num); is not a function call.

Comment: Also, the function should take `int*`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This record

```
swap_numbers(int first_num, int second_num);
```

is not a function call. You have to write at least like

```
swap_numbers( first_num, second_num);
```

Also the function does not swap the objects `first_num` and `second_num` defined in main because it deals with copies of values of the objects.

Also after these lines within the function

```
int temp_num = second_num;

first_num = temp_num;
```

the value of the variable `first_num` is lost. Thus in the next statement

```
second_num = first_num;
```

the variable `second_num` is assigned by itself.

And the function has the return type `int` but returns nothing.

To swap the original variables you need to pass them to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing objects indirectly through pointers to them.

So the function should be declared and defined like

```
void swap_numbers( int *first_num, int *second_num )
{
    int temp_num = *second_num; 
    *second_num = *first_num;
    *first_num = temp_num;
}
```

and the function is called like

```
swap_numbers( &first_num, &second_num );
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand this concept correctly, by assigning a variable to another variable that is being pointed to, it doesn't change the original variable this way. The way that I was doing it was replacing it and therefore giving me the wrong data (or none at all) when i go to use it?

Comment: @RenaeCarter Your function deals with copies of values of the variables. So it tries to swap the copies not the original variables.

Comment: Also, follow up question, in your example of how it should be, are you assigning the value of the referenced second_num variable to temp_num, (which would keep the original value in tact) and are the variables that have an asterisk, the ones that are being pointed to?

Comment: @RenaeCarter You need to read a book about pointers. Dereferencing a pointer you get a direct access to the pointed object.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea there is a whole book just on pointers. Any that you recommend?

Comment: @RenaeCarter You can read any book on C because I am sure in any book there are chapters describing pointers.